# $state vs $scope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Are there any disadvantages to moving everything out of $scope and into $state?

I'm in the process of migrating over to ui-router and I'm finding that $state works very much like $scope, with the added benefit of being able to pass state parameters upon route changes.

I know $state is a subset of $scope but I'm not sure why $scope provides much additional value if it provides similar functionality and is going away in Angular 2.0.

Comment: `$state` and `$scope` are completely different things

Comment: there is a technique to reduce your dependence on `$scope`, using the ControllerAs syntax.  however, it's not possible to use `$state` as a replacement for `$scope` at all.

Comment: @NewDev care to elaborate?

Comment: Might as well just put everything on rootscope ...then try to figure out how to isolate instances of anything. This concept doesn't make sense

Comment: @JamesGentes, I would, but I find it hard to find similarities

Answer (score 2):

Not a good approach. $scope and $state have different meaning. $scope is a model whereas $state is mainly used for routing